# Putnam inspired problem

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, contest-math

The following is a beautiful problem from Putnam 2003

minimize $|\sin x + \cos x + \tan x + \csc x + \sec x + \cot x|$

I was thinking about a small variation of the above problem

> minimize $|\sin x + \cos x + \tan x - \csc x - \sec x - \cot x|$

Thanks.

Comment: Both these values blow up certain trigonometric functions. So incorrect

Comment: Is there a certain limit for $x$? $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, for example?

Comment: @2012ssohn the original Putnam problem had no such limits. But then you naturally expect it to lie in $(-\pi, \pi)$ since the functions are periodic

Comment: Can you represent each as complex exponentials then simplify?

Comment: Ok. I was wondering about the original Putnam problem, and it seems to blow up at $x = 0$, and was wondering whether there are any limitations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $x=-\dfrac{\pi}{4}$. Then $\cos x = -\sin x, \sec x = -\csc x, \tan x = \cot x$ and the expression inside the absolute values is $0$.

Comment: Beautiful. +1 for you.

Comment: +1 This is probably more beautiful than the original Putnam problem.

Comment: Adding integer multiples of $\pi$ gives you more zeros

Comment: @DavidH True enough though the only one that falls into the range mentioned in the comments to the OP is $\frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Comment: That was a good one.

Comment: I believe the minimum value is 2, not 0?

Comment: @ErikMiehling The problem to solve is the one in the gray box. The original problem is an old Putnam problem that inspired the new question.

Comment: @JohnHabert Ah, you are right.